# How to add a html file link in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a project where I need to dynamically load an HTML file using JavaScript. I have a specific HTML file that I want to link and display based on user interactions. However, I'm unsure about the proper method to achieve this.

I have tried using the create Element method along with set Attribute to create a link element, but I am encountering difficulties in making it point to my desired HTML file. Here is a snippet of what I've attempted:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'import');
link.setAttribute('href', 'path/to/my/file.html');
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Despite these efforts, the HTML file doesn't seem to be linked correctly, and I'm not seeing the expected results.

Could someone please guide me on the correct way to add a link to an HTML file using JavaScript? Specifically, how can I dynamically link an external HTML file and ensure it displays appropriately in my project? Any insights, code snippets, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why, why would you want to append a HTML into the `<head>` of your site? Use `<iframe>` not `<link>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link Anyways, unclear what is that you're trying to achieve exactly. Otherwise, you might also use AJAX to fetch a HTML portion to be included in the DOM.

Comment: Read up on `fetch()` and [DOMParser.parseFromString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString).